# Codeigniter URI route /$USERNAME to /user/profile/USERNAME

Tags: regex, codeigniter, preg-match

I have symbol "$" allowed in URL. Every user of my application has a username. I want to show their profiles with website.com/$USERNAME. I want to route /$USERNAME TO /users/profile/USERNAME. I am trying this

when I hard code it like this

```
$route['&#36;username'] = "user/profile/username";
```

its working but when i try it like this...

```
$route['&#36;(:any)'] = "user/profile/$1";
```

its not working...

Any help/suggestions?

Comment: Try this: `$route['&#36;([a-zA-Z_]+)'] = "profile/page/$1";`

Comment: it gives error. **** Severity: Warning ***** Message: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '3' ***** Filename: core/Router.php

Comment: Try  my edit. Regex is not really my best quality

Comment: Sorry couldn't get that... What you mean "my edit"

Comment: Oh, I editted my comment.

Comment: oh okay, it still gives the same error... unknown modifier '3'